# How Can I set UIBarButtonItem as anchor of a popover in IOS?

Tags: ios, ipad, uibarbuttonitem, popover

I show a popover controller in my IPad app:

```
[self.programMapPopOver presentPopoverFromRect:anchor.frame
                        inView:anchor.superview
                        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                        animated:YES];
```

My problem is with anchor: I'd like to set an UIBarButtonItem* as its anchor, but it is not an UIView*, but inView is a view* parameter.

How can I solve this?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to use [`presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPopoverController/presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem%3apermittedArrowDirections%3aanimated%3a).

Comment: Thanks so much, I did not noticed this method, I just concetrated on other and tried to get the view.

Comment: Note that this method was deprecated in iOS 9. In the iOS 9 implementation of popovers, there is an equivalent [`barButtonItem`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontroller/1622314-barbuttonitem) property on a `UIPopoverPresentationController`.

Answer (score 61):

In iOS 8 & 9, the `presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated:` method is deprecated. You'll want to set the `barButtonItem` property on the view controller's `popoverPresentationController` property.

```
let popover = UIViewController()
popover.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
if let presentation = popover.popoverPresentationController {
    presentation.barButtonItem = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
}
presentViewController(popover, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Its not working form me in Swift3 with iOS 10 version. Its showing full screen view controller. What should I change?

Comment: just set popover.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem this is working for me.

Comment: @Satyam This same thing happened to me. I cannot present any popovers that have UINavigationController as the root. I removed the UINavigationController and just present the root VC as popover and it seems to work